# How do I use an svg gradient returned by a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to calculate a gradient based on data included in json. d in this situation is an object within the json that has no further children (leaf of a network). I am trying to use the return of calculateGradient(d) to colour the 'leaf circles' but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function calculateGradient(d){
  var total = d.totalVulnCount;
  var low = (d.vulnCountLow/total * 100);
  var med = (d.vulnCountMed/total * 100);
  var high = (d.vulnCountHigh/total * 100);
  var critical = (d.vulnCountCritical/total * 100)

  var grad = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
           .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("y2", "0%");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", low).style("stop-color", "#fdc500");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", low).style("stop-color", "#fd8c00");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#fd8c00");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#dc0000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", high).style("stop-color", "#dc0000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#780000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", high).style("stop-color", "#780000");

//Gradient colors of circles
return grad;
}

var circle = plotWrapper.append("circle")
        .attr("id", "nodeCircle")
        .attr("class", function(d,i) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? colorCircle(d.depth) : "url(#calculateGradient(d))" }) // for the gradient use "url(#grad)" instead of color
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            if(d.ID === "1.1.1.1") scaleFactor = d.value/(d.r*d.r);
            return d.r;
        })
        .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoomTo(d); else zoomTo(root); });
```

I am most confused as if I was to assign the variable 'grad to the following:

```
  var low = 10%;
  var med = 30%;
  var high = 60%;
  var critical = 100%

  var grad = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
           .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("y2", "0%");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", low).style("stop-color", "#fdc500");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", low).style("stop-color", "#fd8c00");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#fd8c00");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#dc0000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", high).style("stop-color", "#dc0000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", med).style("stop-color", "#780000");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", high).style("stop-color", "#780000");
```

Then using the following works fine:

```
var circle = plotWrapper.append("circle")
        .attr("id", "nodeCircle")
        .attr("class", function(d,i) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? colorCircle(d.depth) : "url(grad)" }) // for the gradient use "url(#grad)" instead of color
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            if(d.ID === "1.1.1.1") scaleFactor = d.value/(d.r*d.r);
            return d.r;
        })
        .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoomTo(d); else zoomTo(root); });
```

But as I require the variable d to be passed in to the function I am unable to do this.

All I really need to know is if it is possible to assign the return of a function to "url(# ...)" ?

I have tried "url(#calculateGradient(d))" and "url(#calculateGradient(d);)" and out of despiration tried "url(#" + calculateGradient(d); +")" but can't get anything to work :( Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
"url(#calculateGradient(d))"
```

Is just setting your gradient to that string.  It does nothing to **invoke** that function.

The fix is to just invoke the function and set fill to `url(#grad)`.  So:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
    if (d.childen){
       return colorCircle(d.depth);
    }else{
       calculateGradient(d); //<-- invoke the function
       return "url(#grad)";
    }
});
```

BTW, you gradient function doesn't need to return anything, you aren't really going to use that value.  Your gradient and circle are linked by the `id` of the gradient.